# i am working on program which select's the ROI of wobbly video and extract the ROI in diff window as stable ROI, want to improve its computation speed

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, image-processing, computer-vision

**The problem is, program is really lengthy and computationally expensive.**

so is there any way to make this program faster or any other way to write this code?

> ***I am beginner in python and would love to take all suggestions or different approach then this program***
>
> ***also i am new to the stack overflow so if anything is wrong in this post or any issue in program please point out in comment .***

first section of code is

```
#TEST V2.1 multitracker
import cv2
import numpy as np

#path = (input("enter the video path: "))
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(" YOUR VIDEO PATH ")
    
    
    # creating the dictionary to add all the wanted trackers in OpenCV that can be used for tracking in future
    OBJECT_TRACKING_MACHINE = {
        "csrt": cv2.legacy.TrackerCSRT_create,
        "kcf": cv2.legacy.TrackerKCF_create,
        "boosting": cv2.legacy.TrackerBoosting_create,
        "mil": cv2.legacy.TrackerMIL_create,
        "tld": cv2.legacy.TrackerTLD_create,
        "medianflow": cv2.legacy.TrackerMedianFlow_create,
        "mosse": cv2.legacy.TrackerMOSSE_create
    }
    
    # Creating the MultiTracker variable object to store the 
    trackers = cv2.legacy.MultiTracker_create()
```

here I started the loop

```
while True:
    frame = cap.read()[1]
    #print("freame start",frame)

    if frame is None:
        print("error getting the video,please check the input")
        break
    frame = cv2.resize(frame,(1080,720))
    Thresh = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    #Thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray, 185, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 11, 6) 
    #print(trackers.update(Thresh))

    (success, boxes) = trackers.update(Thresh)
    
    # loop over the bounding boxes and draw them on the frame
    if success == False:
        bound_boxes = trackers.getObjects()
        idx = np.where(bound_boxes.sum(axis= 1) != 0)[0]
        bound_boxes = bound_boxes[idx]
        trackers = cv2.legacy.MultiTracker_create()
        for bound_box in bound_boxes:
            trackers.add(tracker,Thresh,bound_box)
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(Thresh)
    k = cv2.waitKey(50)
```

**And I am guessing this is the section which is making the program slow**

if is there any different way to represent this part or any idea different then this

```
 for i,box in enumerate(boxes):
        (x, y, w, h) = [int(v) for v in box]
        #cv2.rectangle(Thresh, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 255, 255), 2)
        #cv2.putText(Thresh,('TRACKING BOX NO-'+str(i)),(x+10,y-3),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN,1.0,(255,255,0),2)
        arr = boxes.astype(int)
        if i == 0 :
            Roi = Thresh[(arr[i,1]):(arr[i,1]+arr[i,3]),(arr[i,0]):(arr[i,0]+arr[i,2])]

            murg = cv2.resize(Roi,(300,200))
            cv2.imshow("horizon", murg)
            #print(murg)
                
        if i == 1 :
            Roi1 = Thresh[(arr[i,1]):(arr[i,1]+arr[i,3]),(arr[i,0]):(arr[i,0]+arr[i,2])]
            Roi = Thresh[(arr[(i-1),1]):(arr[(i-1),1]+arr[(i-1),3]),(arr[(i-1),0]):(arr[(i-1),0]+arr[(i-1),2])]

            murg = cv2.resize(Roi,(300,200))
            murg1 = cv2.resize(Roi1,(300,200))
            hori = np.concatenate((murg,murg1),axis=1)
            cv2.imshow("horizon",hori)
            #print(hori)
        elif i == 2 :
            Roi2 = Thresh[(arr[i,1]):(arr[i,1]+arr[i,3]),(arr[i,0]):(arr[i,0]+arr[i,2])]
            Roi1 = Thresh[(arr[(i-1),1]):(arr[(i-1),1]+arr[(i-1),3]),(arr[(i-1),0]):(arr[(i-1),0]+arr[(i-1),2])]
            Roi = Thresh[(arr[(i-2),1]):(arr[(i-2),1]+arr[(i-2),3]),(arr[(i-2),0]):(arr[(i-2),0]+arr[(i-2),2])]

            murg = cv2.resize(Roi,(300,200))
            murg1 = cv2.resize(Roi1,(300,200))
            murg2 = cv2.resize(Roi2,(300,200))
            hori = np.concatenate((murg,murg1,murg2),axis=1)
            cv2.imshow("horizon",hori)
            #print(hori)
        elif i == 3 :
            Roi3 = Thresh[(arr[i,1]):(arr[i,1]+arr[i,3]),(arr[i,0]):(arr[i,0]+arr[i,2])]
            Roi2 = Thresh[(arr[(i-1),1]):(arr[(i-1),1]+arr[(i-1),3]),(arr[(i-1),0]):(arr[(i-1),0]+arr[(i-1),2])]
            Roi1 = Thresh[(arr[(i-2),1]):(arr[(i-2),1]+arr[(i-2),3]),(arr[(i-2),0]):(arr[(i-2),0]+arr[(i-2),2])]
            Roi = Thresh[(arr[(i-3),1]):(arr[(i-3),1]+arr[(i-3),3]),(arr[(i-3),0]):(arr[(i-3),0]+arr[(i-3),2])]

            murg = cv2.resize(Roi,(300,200))
            murg1 = cv2.resize(Roi1,(300,200))
            murg2 = cv2.resize(Roi2,(300,200))
            murg3 = cv2.resize(Roi3,(300,200))
            hori = np.concatenate((murg,murg1,murg2,murg3),axis=1)
            cv2.imshow("horizon",hori)
            #print(hori)
```

this section is so that I can print the ROI matrix  and to select the ROI

```
    if k == ord("1"):
        print(murg)
    if k == ord("2"):
        print(murg1)
    if k == ord ("3"):
        print(murg2)
    if k == ord("4"):
        print(murg3)

    cv2.imshow('Frame', Thresh)
    

    if k == ord("e"):
        break

    if k == ord("s"):
        roi = cv2.selectROI("Frame", Thresh, fromCenter=False,showCrosshair=False)
        tracker = OBJECT_TRACKING_MACHINE['mosse']()
        trackers.add(tracker, Thresh, roi)
    #print(boxes,success)

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

> when you will run this code you can extract 4 ROI frames which will track your ROI's (I haven't added the precaution for empty matrix so it will give you error if you select more than 4 roi's)

my end goal is to extract those ROI videos for Image processing (this code is not done yet and there's more image processing is going to happen in letter part) **

Comment: Maybe you should try https://codereview.stackexchange.com/